# Update Your Amazon RDS SSL/TLS Certificates by October 31, 2019

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database, rds

We recently received an email from AWS called "Update Your Amazon RDS SSL/TLS Certificates by October 31, 2019"

We have tried to follow the guidelines to get ready for the deadline in March 2020, however since our DB instance is in MySQL 5.6, it's unclear if we have to actually perform anything, since from the command line examples provided there is not for version 5.6

Could you please advise on the matter ?

Comment: if there is no SSL certificates already being in used, then what to do with the DB instances (RDS) using our web servers ?
means, currently we are not using any certificates for RDS to communicate.
please advise , is this the communication/ssl certificates related to AWS RDS and web servers on AWS also ?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that this will apply to all in-support MySQL instances regardless of version. Which would include 5.6, yes. The old CA expires uncomfortably soon, so AWS will not be leaving old MySQL versions behind on it. You will need to update your CA-files appropriately.